# Azure deployment slot copy custom domains

Tags: azure, powershell, deployment, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I run a multi-tenant website that has many custom domains.

This is 1 web app that contains 1 site, it allows customers to have a section of the site under their own domain name. Hence 1 web app with many custom domains.

I'm setting up a deployment slot to seamlessly publish new site changes without affecting the end users with downtime etc. So I'll publish changes to the deployment slot, perform some simple testing then swap it in as Production.

The issue is that deployment slots don't copy the custom domains across to the new slot, so is there a way of performing a copy of the current custom domains  when i publish to the slot?

So, for example, in 1 week i get 5 new custom domains added automatically to slot1. (Adding custom domains is triggered by the end user)

I publish new changes to slot2 and swap to this. I need the 5 additional custom domains on slot2 as well.

Anyone had to deal with this yet?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on this, Do you have 5 separate 5 web app which requires swapping mechanism in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this was my misunderstanding.

My production slot contained the custom domains.

My staging slot had no custom domains.

When you swap the slots over what Azure is doing is:

- copying the custom domains and a few other settings to the new destination slot (in this case 'staging') https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots
- Switch the names on the source and destination slots
- swap over the IPs so the staging slot becomes production and vice versa

for more detail check this out https://stackify.com/azure-deployment-slots/